# AngularUI pattern to forward to url after login

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

So I have a scenario where a user can provide a url like:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/component?id=1234
```

The first thing AngularUI does is check if the user is authorized.
If it's not authorized it's forwarded to the login page using

```
$state.go("login");
```

My intention is to record the url in

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart"....
```

Save it in the rootscope and then forward to that url once the login is done.
However, I can't seem to find a way to maintain the url with the query parameter component?id=1234. should I use $location or $state. I can get it to work with the state name only (using $state) but not with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your solution is the best one there. But if you want to do that, you can simply write a function like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
   /* your code here */    
})
```

and you can navigate to any state with any parameters by doing something like:

```
$state.go("state_name",{/*parameters as an object e.g. id:1234*/});
```

You can also read the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) on angular ui-router's page.
Hope I could answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing but I just don't want to parse the parameters into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually turns out I can just use the $location object.

storing $location.url() in the rootScope. and then navigating using $location.url(savedUrl) to redirect it back.